# SharePoint 2010 Parse created by Lastname, Firstname to Firstname Lastname

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to parse the created by displayed user Lastname, Firstname to be displayed Firstname Lastname. I do not mind if this is done through JavaScript as a transposition after the page loads.

Answer (score 2):

No jQuery and easier to continue with

```
var names=document.querySelectorAll(".ms-subtleLink");
names.forEach(function(name){
    var fullname.innerHTML;
    //change fullname your way
    name.innerHTML=fullname;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this with `','` but it should work with the "Modified By" links in a webpart or a list.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ms-subtleLink").each(function(){ $(this).text($(this).text().split(',')[1].toString() + ' ' + $(this).text().split(',')[0]);});
});
```